# How can I parallelize the merge operation on a bidirectional one-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I am coding a parallel clustering algorithm in C#. I have a class called Classification which currently uses a Dictionary to associate a String label with a set of N-dimensional points. Each label has one or more points in its cluster. Classification also has a reverse index that associates each point with its label, which is in a second Dictionary.

The most expensive method currently performs many merge operations. A merge takes all members of a source cluster and moves them to the same target cluster. This operation updates both Dictionaries.

I have multiple processes that identify points that belong together in the same cluster. This relationship is transitive: if A belongs with B and B with C, then A, B and C belong in the same cluster. However, there is no easy way to segment the problem such that each process works on a disjoint subset of points. The processes will be operating on the same points.

How do I implement the merge method to minimize lock contention and assure atomic operations? Here is a portion of my class definition. The final method, Merge, is the one I want to parallelize. That may require me to change my Dictionaries into parallel collections.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Cluster
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represent points grouped into class partitions where each point is associated with a class label 
    /// and each labeled class has a set of points.
    /// 
    /// This does not perform the unassisted clustering of points.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TPoint">Type of the points to be classified.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TLabel">Type of the label that can be associated with a set within the classification.</typeparam>
    public class Classification<TPoint, TLabel> where TLabel : IEquatable<TLabel>
    {

        #region Properties (LabelToPoints, PointToLabel, NumPartitions, NumPoints)

        /// <summary>
        /// Associates a class label with the points belonging to that class.
        /// </summary>
        public Dictionary<TLabel, ISet<TPoint>> LabelToPoints { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Associates a point with the label for its class.
        /// </summary>
        private Dictionary<TPoint, TLabel> PointToLabel { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Total number of class partitions that points are divided among.
        /// </summary>
        public int NumPartitions { get { return LabelToPoints.Count; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Total number of points among all partitions.
        /// </summary>
        public int NumPoints { get { return PointToLabel.Count; } }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public Classification()
        {
            LabelToPoints = new Dictionary<TLabel, ISet<TPoint>>();
            PointToLabel = new Dictionary<TPoint, TLabel>();
        }

        public Classification(IEnumerable<TPoint> points, Func<TPoint,TLabel> startingLabel) : this()
        {
            foreach (var point in points)
            {
                Add(point, startingLabel(point));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new Classification by randomly selecting a subset of the points in the current Classification.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sampleSize">Number of points to include in the new Classification.</param>
        /// <returns>A new Classification that has the given number of points.</returns>
        public Classification<TPoint, TLabel> Sample(int sampleSize)
        {
            var subset = new Classification<TPoint, TLabel>();
            foreach (var point in Points().TakeRandom(sampleSize, NumPoints))
                subset.Add(point,  GetClassLabel(point));
            return subset;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Modify the Classification (Add, Remove, Merge)

        /// <summary>
        /// Add a point to the classification with the associated label.
        /// 
        /// If the point was already classified, its old classification is removed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="p">Point to add.</param>
        /// <param name="classLabel">Label for classification.</param>
        public void Add(TPoint p, TLabel classLabel)
        {
            Remove(p);
            PointToLabel[p] = classLabel;
            EnsurePartition(classLabel).Add(p);
        }

        private ISet<TPoint> EnsurePartition(TLabel classLabel)
        {
            ISet<TPoint> partition;
            if (LabelToPoints.TryGetValue(classLabel, out partition)) return partition;
            partition = new HashSet<TPoint>();
            LabelToPoints[classLabel] = partition;
            return partition;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Remove a point from its class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="p">Point to remove.</param>
        /// <returns>True if the point was removed, false if it was not previously a member of any class.</returns>
        public Boolean Remove(TPoint p)
        {
            TLabel label;
            if (!PointToLabel.TryGetValue(p, out label)) return false;
            PointToLabel.Remove(p);
            var oldPoints = LabelToPoints[label];
            var didRemove = oldPoints.Remove(p);
            if (oldPoints.Count == 0)
                LabelToPoints.Remove(label);
            return didRemove;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Merge all the members of the partitions labeled by any of the labels in sourceLabels
        /// into the partition indicated by targetLabel.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="targetLabel">Move members into this labeled partition.</param>
        /// <param name="sourceLabels">Move members out of these labeled partitions.</param>
        public void Merge(TLabel targetLabel, IEnumerable<TLabel> sourceLabels)
        {
            var targetPartition = EnsurePartition(targetLabel);
            foreach (var sourceLabel in sourceLabels.Where(sLabel => !sLabel.Equals(targetLabel)))
            {
                ISet<TPoint> singleSourcePoints;
                if (!LabelToPoints.TryGetValue(sourceLabel, out singleSourcePoints)) continue;

                // Add to LabelToPoints under new targetLabel
                targetPartition.UnionWith(singleSourcePoints);
                // Remove from LabelToPoints under old sourceLabel.
                LabelToPoints.Remove(sourceLabel);

                foreach (var p in singleSourcePoints)
                    PointToLabel[p] = targetLabel;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**:
I am sure that changing the Dictionaries to ConcurrentDictionary is not enough. I think I need to take out locks on the target label and all the source labels. If any other process is in the middle of performing a merge with any of those labels as source or target, then I need to wait until that other process is done. How do you do this without creating deadlocks? I can sort the labels alphabetically to try and ensure the same order, but is that enough?

**UPDATE 2**:
New approach. I realized that the merge operations are order independent. I will create a multiple producer, single consumer queue. The producers find opportunities to merge, while the consumer serializes access to the Classification object. Since performing the merges takes longer than finding the merge candidates, the consumer won't starve. A better design would get better throughput, but this will still be an improvement.